# checkParameterIsNotNull error in Login Activity sample

Tags: android, null, kotlin

I'm trying to start kotlin with a standard sample in Android Studio. First of all I create new project with Login Activity template, then convert it to use kotlin. But I have **runtime** (not compile) error in this string:

```
loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this)
```

Error listing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter bundle
```

Comment: You don't show the stack trace, maybe it is another method further up the chain when something calls back to Kotlin which then checks the parameter nullability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [`LoaderManager.initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#initLoader(int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E)) is Java code, Kotlin views its parameters as `Int, Bundle!, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D!>!)`. Those exclamation marks are Kotlin's [notation for platform types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types). `Bundle!` means "`Bundle` or `Bundle?`". i.e. It is Kotlin's way of stating that it doesn't know whether a parameter is non-null or nullable.

Android has Java [nullability annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) (namely [`@NonNull`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/NonNull.html) and [`@Nullable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Nullable.html)) that can be used to specify this for compilers, etc. to leverage but they have not been used here. If they were, Kotlin would infer that type is either `Bundle` or `Bundle?` depending on which annotation is present.

Android's documentation for `args: Bundle!` states that it is optional, i.e. `args: Bundle?` (but the Kotlin compiler cannot infer this because it is lacking a `@NonNull` annotation).
If you inspect the full stack trace of the thrown exception I suspect you will find a Kotlin function that receives `args: Bundle` but should receive `args: Bundle?`.

i.e. If you have something like

```
override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle): Loader<Cursor> = TODO()
```

then it should instead be

```
override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> = TODO()
```

because the Kotlin compiler inserts a not-null check for the former but not the latter.

See [Null-Safety and Platform Types - Calling Java from Kotlin - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) for more details.

Comment: I did not think about the callback function parameters that are also unspecified in Java but can be specified in Kotlin. Thanks. The change happened after using the Java to Kotlin converter provided by Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple, just replace `null` to empty `Bundle()`:

```
loaderManager.initLoader(0, Bundle(), this)
```

But I can't understand why kotlin doesn't catch this on-the-fly.

Comment: Kotlin likely would catch it if the error was where the question assumes it is.  The full stack trace likely shows the error happening elsewhere, maybe a callback to Kotlin which has a non nullable variable of same name?

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer is modify the onCreateLoader function

`override fun onCreateLoader(i: Int, bundle: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor>`

Answer (score 0):

```
loaderManager.initLoader(0,myBundle ?: Bundle(),this)
```

If **myBundle** is null *loadermanager* will use Bundle()